# Android MSM kernel: copy_to_user fails

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel driver for a Linux kernel running on Android devices (Nexus 5X).

I have a kernel buffer and I want to expose a device to read from it. I can read and write from the kernel buffer but I cannot write to the userspace buffer received from the `read` syscall. The very strange thing is that `copy_to_user` works only for less than 128 bytes... it makes no sense to me.

The code is the following ( truncated ):

```
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char __user *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
    unsigned long sent;
    // ...
    pr_err("MYLOGGER: copying from buffer: head=%d, tail=%d, cnt=%d, sent=%lu, access=%lu\n",
          head, tail, cnt, sent,
          access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, buffer, sent));

   if(sent >= 1) {
       sent -= copy_to_user(buffer, mybuf + tail, sent);
       pr_err("MYLOGGER: sent %lu bytes\n", sent);
       // ...
   }
    // ...
}
```

The output is the following:

```
[   56.476834] MYLOGGER: device opened
[   56.476861] MYLOGGER: reading from buffer
[   56.476872] MYLOGGER: copying from buffer: head=5666644, tail=0, cnt=5666644, sent=4096, access=1
[   56.476882] MYLOGGER: sent 0 bytes
```

As you can see from the log `sent` is 4096, no integer overflow here.
When using `dd` I'm able to read up to 128 bytes per call ( `dd if=/dev/mylog bs=128` ). I think that when using more than 128 bytes `dd` uses a buffer from the heap and the kernel cannot access it anymore, which is what I cannot understand.

I'm using `copy_to_user` from the `read` syscall handler, I've also printed the `current->pid` and it is the same process.

The kernel sources can be found [from google android sources](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-7.1.1_r0.22).

The function `copy_to_user` is defined at *arch/arm64/include/asm/uaccess.h* and the `__copy_to_user` can be found in *arch/arm64/lib/copy_to_user.S*.

Thank you for your time, I hope to get rid of this madness with your precious help.

-- EDIT --

I've wrote a small snippet to get the `vm_area_struct` of the destination userspace buffer and I print out the permissions, this is the result:

```
MYLOGGER: buffer belongs to vm_area with permissions rw-p
```

So that address should be writable...

-- EDIT --

I've written more debugging code, logging the state of the memory page used by the userspace buffer.

```
MYLOGGER: page=(0x7e3782d000-0x7e3782e000) present=1
```

Long story short it works when the page is present and will not cause a page fault. This is insanely weird, the page fault shall be managed by the virtual memory allocator that would load the page into the main memory...

Comment: use simple_read_from_buffer(buf, length, offset, &kbuffer, BUFF_LEN)

Comment: @AlexHoppus thank you for the suggestion, as you can see from [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-7.1.1_r0.22/fs/libfs.c#582) it is only a wrapper around `copy_to_user`. I already check the parameters and subsequent reads works fine ( read offsets are ok )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I held a `spin_lock`.

`copy_{to,from}_user` shall never be called while holding a spin_lock.
Using a `mutex` solves the problem.

I feel so stupid to had wasted days on this...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if the page is not present in memory the kernel will **not** fetch it.

My best guess is the [`__copy_to_user` assembly function](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-7.1.1_r0.22/arch/arm64/lib/copy_to_user.S) exception handler, which returns the number of uncopied bytes.

This exception handler is executed before the virtual memory page fault callback. Thus you won't be able to write to userspace unless the pages are already present in memory.

My current workaround is to preload those pages using `get_user_pages`.

I hope that this helps someone else :)

Comment: `Thus you won't be able to write to userspace unless the pages are already present in memory.` - This is definitely an unexpected behavior of `copy_to_user` - look like a bug.